# How to disable click in Listbox c#/.net

Tags: c#, click, listbox-control

I have added many items in my listbox and I am using selected items of listbox using this code:

```
  listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;
```

I also want to disable click in listbox. Please tell me how can I disable click in listbox when program is running.

Answer (score 2):

Simply set the [`Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property to false to disable user interaction.

However, this sounds as if you're (ab)using the GUI to implement application logic. Shouldn't you use a `List<something>` to store and iterate through your items and update your ListBox from the List<> instead of depending on what's on screen?